# List of Votes by Authenticated users

Tags: support, api-v2, api-v2.2, users, voting

In [the API documentation for the question type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question), it says that you can access, *for a specific question*, whether or not the authenticated user (in the private_info scope) upvoted/downvoted the question.

**Is there any way to filter for questions based on this information?** That is, given an authenticated user, I would like to fetch a list of the questions for which they have cast up/down votes.

Comment: Also mentioned at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175722/200117 Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278090/can-i-see-who-i-voted-for

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  Currently [the `users` type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) does not return any `private_info` and neither does [the `user_timeline` type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user-timeline) return any voting information.

No other API method allows for detecting a user's vote history except one question at a time.  You would have to fetch every single question and test the `downvoted` and the `upvoted` properties.

---

If you limited your search only to questions asked since the user's last visit you *might* be able to brute-force this for votes on *new* questions 
([Even Stack Overflow only runs about 7.5K questions per day](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) (Quota is 10K calls, max 100 Q's per call))
-- but I wouldn't recommend it.
And, you'd miss new votes on old, established questions.

---

Update: [At least one script](https://stackapps.com/questions/6755/get-a-list-of-posts-youve-voted-on-that-have-been-edited) works around this and fetches voting history by scraping the:

- `/users/current/?tab=votes&sort=upvote`
  and
- `/users/current/?tab=votes&sort=downvote`

pages.