# Get a list of posts you've voted on that have been edited

Tags: script, voting

#### About

Many posts over the years have asked for ways to systematically ensure up- and down-votes are as up-to-date as the posts they were cast on, whether by notifying as soon as a post was edited, or by listing posts that now qualify for retracting votes. This script was inspired by [this suggestion in particular for the latter](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179911/adding-an-edited-section-to-the-votes-tab). It adds a dynamic tab to the Votes tab on your profile, showing only votes on posts that have been changed since you voted. (The date shown is the date you voted, not the date of the last revision.)

#### License

[Version 3 of the GPL](https://github.com/TuggyNE/ShowEditedVotes/blob/master/LICENSE) or any later version.

#### Screenshots

Once you go to the votes tab on your profile, you'll see this:
[image: "edited since voting" link added at end of filter subtabs]

Click it, as shown, and after the progress indicator thrashes for a while you'll see a count of qualifying votes to the left:
[image: vote count display, modified]

Below will be assorted votes in the same tabular format as normal votes (though without inline post bodies):
[image: an up- and a down-vote]

Refresh or retract your votes by opening the linked posts, of course.

#### Install

[Install Show Edited Votes](https://github.com/TuggyNE/ShowEditedVotes/raw/master/Show_Edited_Votes.user.js).

#### Known Issues

- Votes are *roughly* sorted first by type (up, down) and then by date.
- Currently broken and unmaintained (at least by me).

#### Version History

Most of this is reflected to some degree in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TuggyNE/ShowEditedVotes/) (converted from hg and filtered of commits to unrelated userscripts).

- 1.0.13: Initial release on M.SE with downvotes only.
- 1.0.23: Fix for crucial date-filtering glitch on M.SE.
- 1.1.12: Handle up-votes as well; more flexibility in use. First release on SA.
- 1.2.05: Work on per-site metas.
- 1.3.01: Works accurately on more sites.
- 1.4.03: Only show downvotes on downvotes subtab, upvotes likewise (but show all if on neither).
- 1.5.00: Uses API key.

Comment: Along the same line of thought, I've always wished there was a lock icon next to each vote, which would disappear if the post was edited and my vote can now change.

Comment: I have mentioned this script on [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346211/3773011).

Comment: @Makyen: Thanks for the mention! I've sifted through the docs and managed to get an API key now.

Comment: I just re-noticed: It would be helpful to also include the year in the dates which are along the left side of the listing. Hmm.. Now that I look closer, it is unclear what is being displayed: the last edit date or the date I voted. In addition, the sorting appears off. I have some where the tooltip is showing years sorted out of order (example [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov62o.gif), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiRIT.gif)). What would probably be best is to have 2 columns of dates (sortable, ideally). one column being the date the user voted and the other being the date the post was edited.

Comment: BTW: It would be helpful if you would provide licensing information (if any). The [parent page](https://www.tuggycomputer.com/nathan/software/) indicates that the scripts shown on that page are under the GPL.  However, that does not actually include this script, or anything else in [this directory](https://www.tuggycomputer.com/nathan/software/userscripts/), which is not explicitly linked from that parent page. FYI: If this was up on GitHub (with a stated license), I probably would have just forked it, investigated the sorting issue, then probably fix it and submitted a pull request.

Comment: I was going to recommend this script on MSO, but it looks like this broke at some point in time, probably prior to 2019-12-30, which is the date the answer below was posted. As I noted above, without an explicit license, all I'm permitted to do is report here that there's an issue.With an explicit license, and preferably some online version-control system (e.g. GitHub), it would be possible for me to just fix it and submit a Pull Request.

Comment: Could we please get this fixed? It sounds like there are takers with the desire to jump in and fix it if you could just clarify the licensing info, since there is no license in [the directory](https://www.tuggycomputer.com/nathan/software/userscripts/) which contains this script.

Comment: @zcoop98: They say better late than never….

Comment: @Makyen: All right, I finally bestirred myself to fix hosting and licensing.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Great! Thanks! I'm a bit busy at the moment, so won't be able to do anything immediately, but I greatly appreciate you updating this so it's possible for others to contribute.

Answer (score 3):

## This should be adopted by SE

I'm a moderator on one of the sites. This would be an amazing tool so I can keep better track of posts.

The main feature it lacks is quicker access through the header bar, somehow.

If adopted, I'd want:

- Options for daily or weekly notifications for *significant* edits on downvotes
- A list of posts that *have not* been edited since downvoting
- A direct link on one of the menus from the header bar

Comment: Currently it is broken in Chrome and not working at all in Firefox.

Comment: I appreciate the support, and I'm glad you see potential here! Unfortunately, I'm no longer very active on SE, so I don't use the script or maintain it, and it broke two years ago or so due to some SE changes. Forks from the linked repo would be welcome (and I'd love to list some here) or even PRs.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed this script and tried it on my gamingSE profile. It does not add the tab shown in your post. Maybe it broke after some update to the website?

I use Firefox and have verified that it's not the fault of my adblocker.

Answer (score 0):

Saw that the script was updated (v1.6.00), sweet! But now I'm getting an error when I attempt to use it. Navigating to the votes page and then clicking the "Editing since voting" item gives me this:

> Show Edited Votes: Finished 'downvote-paging' state unexpectedly

[image: Browser alert shown with the text "Show Edited Votes: Finished 'downvote-paging' state unexpectedly"]