# Is the way to search answers by who I voted for?

Tags: support, feature-request, api-v2.2, search, voting

I found few similar questions: [first](https://stackapps.com/questions/4725/list-of-votes-by-authenticated-users), [second](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278090/can-i-see-who-i-voted-for). But answers is too old (2014 year). It's actual now — no way to get this info by using API?

Comment: There's almost no feature development on the API, so the old Q&A still applies: [List of Votes by Authenticated users](https://stackapps.com/questions/4725/list-of-votes-by-authenticated-users)

Comment: Can I vote up to this feature? Maybe you have some backlog?

Comment: You can upvote that question (maybe you already did) but there's no backlog you can vote on. The API simply hasn't that much priority right now, since it's pretty complete.